# Selection pattern in GREP

Tags: text, grep

I have a big file with multiple lines:

```
HETATM 4373 C117 OL     33       9.263  58.080  60.981  1.00  0.00      MEMB C
HETATM 4374 H17R OL     33       8.636  57.596  61.761  1.00  0.00      MEMB H
HETATM 4375 H17S OL     33       8.582  58.712  60.368  1.00  0.00      MEMB H
HETATM 4376 C118 OL     33      10.292  58.992  61.644  1.00  0.00      MEMB C
HETATM 4377 H18R OL     33       9.777  59.849  62.127  1.00  0.00      MEMB H
HETATM 4378 H18S OL     33      10.998  59.390  60.886  1.00  0.00      MEMB H
HETATM 4379 H18T OL     33      10.874  58.445  62.416  1.00  0.00      MEMB H
TER 
TER LEU 3030
```

I need to past from the doc the lines which are only begin with HETATM or TER but not with TER + something else.
E.g using

```
 grep -E "HETATM|TER" ${ref} > output
```

It selects both types of TER records. How to specify more accurately the second selection to obtain

```
HETATM 4373 C117 OL     33       9.263  58.080  60.981  1.00  0.00      MEMB C
HETATM 4374 H17R OL     33       8.636  57.596  61.761  1.00  0.00      MEMB H
HETATM 4375 H17S OL     33       8.582  58.712  60.368  1.00  0.00      MEMB H
HETATM 4376 C118 OL     33      10.292  58.992  61.644  1.00  0.00      MEMB C
HETATM 4377 H18R OL     33       9.777  59.849  62.127  1.00  0.00      MEMB H
HETATM 4378 H18S OL     33      10.998  59.390  60.886  1.00  0.00      MEMB H
HETATM 4379 H18T OL     33      10.874  58.445  62.416  1.00  0.00      MEMB H
TER
```

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

```
 grep '^HETATM$\|^TER$' file
```

will select lines contains only `HETATM` or `TER`.

E.g

```
TER PRO 312
```

won't be matched.

Comment: It actually did not select nothing in my file

Comment: @JamesStarlight perhaps you have trailing spaces.  It matches lines only containing `HETATM` or `TER`. As you wished. Trailing spaces after TER for me is same as `TER + something else.` Better paste the expected output in your question.

Comment: you are right! i have a lines which are begins with HETATM but actually consist of something else like HETATM  712  C12 PA      6      59.634  27.021  70.915  1.00  0.00      MEMB C       but actually grep -E "^HETATM" select them good

Comment: I modified the first message